# Print button on CR306000 to print case data

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom button on CR306000 to try to print current loaded case information by calling one customized report. Navigation URL current set to:

```
~/Frames/ReportLauncher.aspx?ID=Inquirycase.rpx&CASEID=####
```

I will need to have custom programming to assign current case ID to replace "####", but don't know where and how to reference that custom button and modify its property.  Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a report parameter called 'CaseID' to your report and call it using the following code using an AEF extension like this:

```
public class CRCaseMaintExtension : PXGraphExtension<CRCaseMaint>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        //if adding to an existing menu button do that here...
        //  Example:
        //Base.Inquiry.AddMenuAction(this.CustomReportButton);
    }

    public PXAction<CRCase> CustomReportButton;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Custom Report", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    public virtual IEnumerable customReportButton(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        if (Base.Case.Current != null)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters["CaseID"] = Base.Case.Current.CaseID.ToString();

            //enter in your report id/number here
            string reportNumber = "Inquirycase"; 

            //opens the report using the defined parameters
            throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, reportNumber, "Custom Report");  
        }

        return adapter.Get();
    }
}
```

I have not tested the above but this should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand the code you provided, but just not sure  how to generate button click event at all from  customization project interface Acumatica provided.

Comment: I added the graph extension code to include a sample of how you could call code from a button. Note that if there is already a reports menu button it would be best to add your report button to this menu button. I do not know if this graph/page contains one but this example above includes the AddMenuAction example if needed. If you do this you might need to set your PXUIField on your button to visible = false

Comment: Thanks a lot, Brendan.